# Why is sort(by:) unavailable in extensions to MutableCollection?

Tags: swift, protocols, extension-methods

I'm trying to write an extension to `MutableCollection` that needs to utilise the `sort(by:)` method for sorting, however it doesn't appear to be available to `MutableCollection` extensions, despite this method being defined for `MutableCollection` (at least according to the Apple Developer Documentation).

Here's a very contrived and simplified example:

```
struct MyType { var priority:Int }
extension MutableCollection where Element == MyType {
    mutating func sort() { self.sort(by: { $0.priority > $1.priority }) }
}
```

But this results in the error `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments`, this is because my own `sort()` method is being seen at this point, there appears to be no awareness of `sort(by:)` at all.

If I change the extension to instead be for `Array` then the extension works just fine, but of course it's then type-specific, rather than applying to all types conforming to `MutableCollection`, which is what I really intended (in order to be as general-purpose as possible).

Why am I unable to see and use the `sort(by:)` method at this point, and is there some way that I can workaround this?

Comment: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7513

Comment: Try `sorted`instead of `sort`. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is a little misleading. In order to sort in place, the collection must also be a `RandomAccessCollection`:

```
struct MyType { var priority:Int }
extension MutableCollection where Self: RandomAccessCollection, Element == MyType {
    mutating func sort() { self.sort(by: { $0.priority > $1.priority }) }
}
```

Comment: Aha! How did you discover this, did it require delving into the source code? It seems the documentation desperately needs to include constraints for methods like these, as I'm sure I'm going to run into similar issues at some point.

Comment: Yeah; I go to the source all the time to figure out how things really work. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d282b1c541baa3b4f5968c0bd828620a35056471/stdlib/public/core/CollectionAlgorithms.swift#L645-L733